# Why in Malloc() function it allocated more byte than actual specified?

Tags: c++

I allocates memory using `malloc(1)` i.e it allocated one byte but it accept number more than of 1 byte. Here in this code it accept 1000 number and it is not possible to store this number in 1 byte.
code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int *a; 
    a=(int *)malloc(1);
    for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)
    {
        a[i]=i;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)
    {
        cout<<""<<a[i];
    }
}
```

why this happen?

Comment: There is nothing stopping you from doing undefined behaviour, it has nothing to do with `malloc`

Comment: please don't spam tags. this has nothing to do with java.

Comment: Neither C nor C++ have bounds checking. If you go out of bounds of allocated memory you have *undefined behavior*. End of story. I know there are *exact* duplicates of this question here, if you just search a little.

Comment: Please try `10000000` instead of `1000`.

Comment: @Jonas I don't think changing 1000 to 10000000 would still have any issue. If there is space (malloc's padding alignment and what not) for int, there is space for int. Doesn't matter what you store.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya making the change will produce a *segmentation fault*. Which in-turn exemplifies the existence of the error

Comment: @Jonas, I am sorry I was only looking at the value being assigned not the a[i].

Comment: @Jonas Technically, it _may_ produce a _segmentation fault_, because, as is the case for UB - nothing is guaranteed.

Answer (score 2):

It's **undefined behavior** because `C` and `C++` doesn't actually do any boundary checking with regards to arrays.

Answer (score 0):

arrays don't have any boundary check conditions.
if your OS or the framework is much efficient it will throw segmentation fault.

Comment: this should have been a comment